# PhD in [your-field] Candidate vs. PhD Candidate in [your-field]?

Tags: phd

I am currently in the third year of my PhD and I find myself in the never-ending process of updating my CV. While updating it, I wrote “PhD in Economics Candidate”, but now I have seen other people in my same situation writing “PhD Candidate in Economics”. **Which of these options is the best option?**

Thank you all very much in advance for your time.

Comment: This is not a question about academia. It's a question about the English language. FWIW, I would use the latter option but I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: @Roland, I agree on both points, and I am a native speaker. "PhD Candidate is what you are so it is a complete idea. The field adds context when needed. "Economics PhD Candidate" also works.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I didn’t realise it was an English (more than an academic) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a formal standard to use, but most people prefer to say "PhD candidate in [field]" because it then makes it clearer the candidacy is for the PhD and not the field.

Comment: -1 because there is a formal standard to use, dictated by the rules of English grammar. The phrase "PhD in economics candidate" is simply incorrect.